# RNN with more weights on recent data

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, data-science, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on LSTM RNN on stock prediction sample data. It seems the RNN is not giving more weights to
recent data.The weights is equally shared in different time steps in RNN. Do we have an option to increase the weight for recent data? (With any parameters in LSTM OR RNN).

Can you correct me or give some more inputs on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why most time-series models now have an attention mechanism. As the attention mechanism is better at learning the relevant time steps. It is also why some people are now using the transformer. RNN/LSTM don't learn long range dependencies well. For instance the [DA-RNN paper](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eyaq007/DA-RNN.pdf) states

> In the first stage, we introduce an in- put attention mechanism to adaptively extract rel- evant driving series (a.k.a., input features) at each time step by referring to the previous encoder hid- den state. In the second stage, we use a temporal attention mechanism to select relevant encoder hid- den states across all time steps.

The key word being across all time steps. You can find implementations of several attention/transformer based models [here](https://github.com/AIStream-Peelout/flow-forecast) (disclaimer I'm the maintainer of this framework).